# iOS: How to disable or handle next and previous buttons in UIWebView HTML5 movie player

Tags: ios, html, cordova, uiwebview

In my iOS Phonegap application, we are playing youtube video inside a UIWebView using a cordova plugin. Below is the code I am using to embed the youtube video in UIWebView. We are using iFrame tag to embed the video.

```
customWebView= [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 374)];
customWebView.delegate=self;
customWebView.scrollView.bounces=NO;
[customWebView setOpaque:NO];
customWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webViewBackground addSubview:customWebView];


NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\body {\background-color: #000000;\
color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<iframe width=\"512\" height=\"374\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlVideo];
[customWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

The video is playing perfectly fine. Both in normal mode and full screen mode. But in full screen mode, user can see the previous and next buttons. On click of next and previous button few times, the video is getting over and I can see only a black screen in webview.

Below are the screenshots.

[image: full screen mode]

[image: after pressing the next or previous button]

Is there anyway we can disable the next and previous buttons in a iFrame video player? Or Is there any other way in which we can handle this?